# Log Concavity of generalized Wishart matrices

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a random $n \times d$ matrix such that all entries of $X$ are distributed as i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, standard normal distribution.

We consider the random $d \times d$ matrix, $S : =X^T\cdot X$ which is distributed as a Wishart matrix $\mathcal{W}_d(\mathrm{I}_d, n)$. Even though the normal distribution is a log concave measure, the same need not be true for $S$, which may not be log concave. However it is well known that if $d > n$ then $S$ turns out to be log concave.

My question is about a generalization of this fact.
 Formally, let $X$ be a random $n \times d$ matrix with i.i.d. entries taken from some isotropic log concave measure $\mu$. Suppose in addition that $d > n$, is it true that the random matrix $X^T\cdot X$ is log concave as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an answer to my old question.

It is not necessarily true $X^T\cdot X$ will be log concave when the entries of $X$ are i.i.d. according to some log concave measure $\mu$.

For a counterexample, take any log-concave measure $\mu$ which is not sub-Gaussian, so that if $v \sim \mu$ then $v^2$ is not sub-exponential and hence cannot be log concave.  Hence, the entries in the diagonal of $X^T\cdot X$ cannot be log concave, which shows that  $X^T\cdot X$ is not log concave.